UserWarning: Low image data range; displaying image with stretched contrast
My code:
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imshow

array_1 = np.array([[255,0],[0,255]])
imshow(array_1, cmap = 'gray')

Output I get:
UserWarning: Low image data range; displaying image with stretched contrast.
  lo, hi, cmap = _get_display_range(image)
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x0000018800153230>

I was trying to get a 2*2 matrix with white, black/black, white
but the code is showing low data range.

This is just a warning, not an error...

also not OpenCV. why did you add that tag? -- [mre] required. two of your six imports were actually used, and the third one is used implicitly.

How did you get on with my answer?

If you print array_1.dtype, you'll see it is int64 which means it can store numbers in the range -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and your actual range of 0..255 is rather small within that range.
You need to specify the dtype yourself - I am assuming you want an unsigned 8-bit range, so:
array_1 = np.array([[255,0],[0,255]], np.uint8)

